# Problems with the JSON object in old version of IE

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer

As a test to make sure calls to the JSON object don't fail in IE I recently added this to my js library:

```
//Works
//if(!JSON) var JSON={};
//JSON.stringify = JSON.stringify || function(){};
//Works
//if(!window.JSON) JSON={};
//JSON.stringify = JSON.stringify || function(){};
//Does not work
//if(!JSON) JSON={};
//JSON.stringify = JSON.stringify || function(){};
//Best of both!
if(!window.JSON) var JSON={};
JSON.stringify = JSON.stringify || function(){};
```

When I say "does not work" I mean it doesn't work in IE7 and throws a "JSON blah blah blah" error. Why does specifying window.JSON not throw the error? And why would not specifying window.JSON but using a var JSON not throw an error? Is this just silly IE stuff I shouldn't worry about or is the result of this dangerous and going to be a problem for other browsers?

Note the same is true for "console".

Comment: If you read the error, it would be something like `Error: 'JSON' is undefined`, which might have led you to the answer. Anyway, chuckj nailed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing an undefined global variable will always throw. Accessing an undefined property of an object will always return `undefined`. The fact that window is an alias for global doesn't change the rules here, accessing a undefined member of window will return `undefined`.

As for why the second example doesn't throw is because all `var`s are hoisted to the enclosing scope regardless of where they appear and before any code is executed in that scope. This means the `JSON` variable is defined even if the `var` is not executed, it will just contain `undefined`. `var` does two things, creates a variable in scope and, optionally, intializes the variable. Creating the variable is hoisted to the top of the scope, assigning it is performed where it appears. All variable contain `undefined` until they are assigned a value. If the assignment is not executed they will remain `undefined`. Duplicate `var` in the same scope are ignored. This means that if `JSON` is already in scope, the `var` is ignored.

This is not silly IE stuff, all ES5 conforming JavaScript implementation need to follow the rules I outlined above.

Comment: +1. While all variables should always be declared, there are times when such things are beyond your control. The safe way to access a variable that may not be defined or declared is to use `typeof`.

Comment: It's going to take a while to absorb that answer but it looks promising! I keep thinking, why doesn't Chrome or FF throw but it's because console and JSON *ARE* defined for those browsers.